# Jetpack Compose: Detect child item overflow and add more badge

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**Goal**

I want to fit as many items as possible to available space and add "+{num}" badge to the end to indicate if there are more items left. Something like below image.

[image]

**Problem**

Since number and size of the items (i.e chips in this case) and also available space are not known beforehand it is difficult to know exactly how many chips would fit. Additionally, compose measures children only once and lays out right away.

**What I've tried**

I tried the following approach but it is not quite there yet.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Column {

        val states = arrayOf(
            "NY", "CA", "NV", "PA", "AZ", "AK", "NE", "CT", "CO", "FL", "IL", "KS", "WA"
        )

        var chipCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

            ChipRow(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(end = 4.dp)
                    .weight(1f, fill = false),
                onPlacementComplete = { chipCount = it }
            ) {
                for (state in states) {
                    Chip(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(4.dp)
                            .wrapContentSize(), text = state
                    )
                }
            }

            Text(text = "+${states.size - chipCount}", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Chip(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Surface(
        color = Color.LightGray,
        shape = CircleShape,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChipRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onPlacementComplete: (Int) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables, constraints ->

        val placeables = measurables.map { it.measure(constraints) };

        var counter = 0

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            var xPosition = 0
            for (placeable in placeables) {
                if (xPosition + placeable.width > constraints.maxWidth) break
                placeable.placeRelative(x = xPosition, 0)
                xPosition += placeable.width
                counter++
            }
            onPlacementComplete(counter)
        }
    }
}
```

First of all it looks hacky rather than a legit solution. Secondly, it doesn't work as intended. The output is like below.

[image]

**Request**

I went through official guides for custom layouts and did many google searches. But couldn't come up with anything better. Could you help with this situation? Reference links, pointing errors, etc., anything is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be aware that calling `onPlacementComplete` during the layout phase to update the `chipCount` may cause a [recomposition loop](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/phases#recomp-loop) and may degrade the performance of your app. I think `SubcomposeLayout` is more appropriate for the layout you're trying to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've passed your max constraint values (`layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight)`), that's why your view took whole screen.

You need to pass the needed view size instead, for example like this:

```kotlin
data class Item(val placeable: Placeable, val xPosition: Int)

val items = mutableListOf<Item>()
var xPosition = 0
for (placeable in placeables) {
    if (xPosition + placeable.width > constraints.maxWidth) break
    items.add(Item(placeable, xPosition))
    xPosition += placeable.width
}

layout(
    width = items.last().let { it.xPosition + it.placeable.width },
    height = items.maxOf { it.placeable.height }
) {
    items.forEach {
        it.placeable.place(it.xPosition, 0)
    }
    onPlacementComplete(items.count())
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i am not too sure either but i think you need to state the column and row width first to make it centervertically.

and i dont think u need `1f` in weight, instead `0.8f` would be better i believe.

```
Column (
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
){

        val states = arrayOf(
            "NY", "CA", "NV", "PA", "AZ", "AK", "NE", "CT", "CO", "FL", "IL", "KS", "WA"
        )

        var chipCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

            ChipRow(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(end = 4.dp)
                    .weight(0.8f, fill = false),
                onPlacementComplete = { chipCount = it }
            ) {
                for (state in states) {
                    Chip(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(4.dp)
                            .wrapContentSize(), text = state
                    )
                }
            }

            Text(text = "+${states.size - chipCount}", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
        }
    }
```

or i would prefer you use constraintlayout instead. [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout)